# SQLite update query with two tables with foreign key

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, foreign-keys

In an sqlite database I have two tables: "**substances**" and "**densities**" with columns "*id*, *name*" (for **substances** table) and "*id*, *substanceid*, *density*" (for **densities** table). *substanceid* has a foreign key (references *id* of the **substances** table). *substanceid* is UNIQUE, so there are the same amount of rows in both tables (each row corresponding to one *substanceid*)

I want to update *density* and *name* for a certain *substanceid*, i.e. one row in each table, but struggle a bit with the syntax for updating the **substances** table.

The **densities** table I can update with:

```
UPDATE densities
SET density = obj.getDensity()
WHERE id = obj.getId();
```

The obj contains (*id, density, name*), but not *substanceId*.

For the **substances** table I would like to write something like:

```
UPDATE substances
SET name = obj.getName()
WHERE id = ???
```

And the "???" in prose would be:

densities.substanceid for which densities.i = obj.getId

How do I write this in SQLite?

Comment: May I ask why don't you have a single "substances" table, "density" being a column?

Comment: And by the way, have a quick read on "ON UPDATE CASCADE" action and see if it helps.

Comment: Good question, and no good answer. I used to have a single table, which I then split, on the one hand to learn/practice a bit with foreign keys and also because it confused me a bit having the substances together with the densities. The substances are also going to be referenced through foreign keys to other database tables.

Comment: I read about "ON UPDATE CASCADE" but as far as I understand this is only useful if I wanted to update the id, which I don't want (it is autoincremented). I do have "ON UPDATE DELETE" though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a scalar subquery:

```
UPDATE substances
SET name = obj.getName()
WHERE id = (SELECT substanceid
            FROM densities
            WHERE i = obj.getId());
```